# Replicate GIT repository over multiple geolocations

Tags: git

We are facing to problems with speed of GIT central repository (cloning, pulling and pushing), which is at overseas.

Our idea is create clone of that repository in our local office.

Has anyone recommendation or experience with similar scenario?

Comment: ...push and clone less? The great thing about `git` is you can do all your work and commits locally, and then push/pull at your leisure later, so rather than pushing every commit just push once per day.  Your general idea of using a local clone works though (see Alex's answer, and note that you can probable use pre/post receive hooks to make things closer to real-time...)

Answer (score 3):

Since git is distributed by nature this seems to be pretty straitforward. For example the following scenario is possible: a team works with a local repo in the office performing pulls and pushes as if it was a central repo and a cron script pushes from that repo to the "real" central repo. If there are other developers a dedicated person will have to perform pulls from the remote repo and resolve conflicts manually if they occur. If conflicts are unlikely you can automate pulls as well.